# Redirect/Rewrite without changing address (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to have a promo page as a temporary replacement for a main page.

```
mydomain.com/page.php to mydomain.com/page-promo.php
```

I already have a rewrite rule to convert html to php

```
# HTML to PHP
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

With the promo page, I want the URL in the user's address bar to remain `mydomain.com/page.php` and this whole thing needs to work if they use .php or .html (I think I just need to put the new rule after the html->php rule)

What syntax is used to prevent the URL address bar from showing the real (promo) address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# assuming /page.php is just a single page
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ page-promo.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

However if /page.php can be any other page then use:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.php$ $1-promo.php [L,NC]
```